# can a set have elements and sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have couple of questions about set theory.

1) suppose that

$$X=\{1,2 ,3 , \{1\}, \{2,3\}\}$$
So is $X$ a correct set? 
I know that there is a set of sets, but can a set be a collection of elements and sets?

2) let 
$$A=\{a │a \text{ is a proper subset of X},X=\{x\} \}$$

Is $A$ an empty set? 
My understanding to proper subset is that if $$ A ⊂ B $$ then $A$ has some of $B$ elements but not all of them. And since $X$ in the above has only one element, then $A$ should be empty. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Note for 2) that $\emptyset \in A$, so $A$ isn't empty.

Comment: Anything can be a member of a set. Any list of things can be the list of all the members of a set. In pure set theory everything is a set :E.g.  $0=\emptyset, $ $ 1=0\cup \{0\}=\{0\}, $ $  2=1\cup \{1\}, $ $ 3=2\cup \{2\},  $ etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes. The set $X$ is simply a subset of $\mathbb{N} \cup 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

2) No. The empty set $\emptyset$ is a proper subset of $X$, and hence $\emptyset \in A$ (that's right: there is nothing stopping the empty set from being an element of a set).

Comment: Thank you, now I have a full picture

Answer (score 2):

For (1), yes, that's fine. Indeed, in [the usual set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) *everything* is a set - so all sets are sets of sets!

For (2), you're not quite right: a set of the form "$\{x\}$" *does* have a proper subset. HINT: what's a set that's a subset of *any* set?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, a set can consist of sets and elements. Let A = {1,2,{4,5,7,4,5,3},9}
then A would contain 1,2,9 and all the elements of set {4,5,7,4,5,3}.

2) an empty set is a subset to any set. Let A = {a,b,c}, then A = {a,b,c,{}}
so A is a subset of X, though it does not contain any elements of X except for the empty set